# If the systems $Ax=u$ and $Ax=v$ don't have solutions, is it possible that $Ax=u+v$ has a solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

For instance, for $u=(0,2,4,6)^T$ and $v=(1,3,5,7)^T$, is it possible that the system
$$
Ax=u+v
$$
has a solution if $Ax=u$ and $Ax=v$ have no solution? I know that if $Ax=b$ and $Ay=b$ with $x$ and $y$ solutions of the system, then $A(x-y)=0$, although this is not the case.

Comment: Ask yourself: take $V=Span(e_1+e_2)$ in $R^2$, which would be the image of your application $A$. Take $u=e_1$ and $v=e_2$. Does it work? Can you adapt this to a 4x4 matrix now? (Btw: is $A$ fixed or whatever you want? Because it depends on whether $A$ has maximal rank or not ..)

Answer (score 4):

If $Ax=u$    has no solution, it is also true that $Ax = -u$  has no solution. So we are saying  your $v=-u$

Next,

$Ax = u + v = u +(-u) = u-u=0$  always has a solution

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*. If $Ax=b$ has a solution and $Ax=u$ doesn't, then $Ax=b-u$ also doesn't.

$\big[$ It's a lot like asking if the sum of irrationals can be rational. The rationals are an additive subgroup of the reals, and the irrationals are its set-theoretic complement. The set of $b$ for which $Ax=b$ has a solution is a subspace of whatever vector space you're working with, and the set of $u$ for which $Ax=u$ doesn't have a solution is its set-theoretic complement. $\big]$

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Let's consider this scenario: the column space of A is a plane through origin, and u is a line through origin but not on the plane, v is an another line through origin but not on the plane, so u and v satisfy $Ax=u$ and $Ax=v$ don't have solutions. But it is evident that v+u is possible to be on the plane (you can have a try on Scratch paper), so $Ax=u+v$ is possible to have a solution despite $Ax=u$ and $Ax=v$ don't have solutions. In conclusion, it has no direct connection between these equations.

Comment: Sometimes it may be more intuitive to analyze a problem from an image perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve consulted "Introduction to Linear Algebra" by Gilbert Strang and I've already solved it. According to your answers, it is posible to have a matrix $A$ with such characteristics.

In the specific case when $Ax=u$ and $Ax=v$ don't have solution, it is posible that $Ax=(u+v)$ has a solution if $u+v$ is in the columns space of $A$ while $v$ and $u$ don't. Therefore, the columns space of $A$ is made up of vector of the form c(u+v) with $c \in R$.